# Issue with TFS VersionControlServer GetWorkspace throwing ItemNotMappedException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs-sdk

I have a small chunk of code that constantly fails when I try to get the workspace.

```
        var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://mytfs.com/projects"));
        var versionControlServer = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        var workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(@"C:\MyProjects\ProjectA\BranchA");
```

I've verified that it's mapped in TFS (by, ya know, having worked on several branches of ProjectA over a couple years). I also specifically checked the mapping after I received the ItemNotMappedException and every level is mapped (C:\MyProjects was explicitly mapped, C:\MyProjects\ProjectA was explicitly mapped, and c:\MyProjects\ProjectA\BranchA is mapped).

No matter what variation I pass to versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(), it throws that error.

This is the extent of my TFS code. I have the TFS project collection correct (it failed a couple times until I found the exact url).

Just so you're aware, the only thing I want to be able to do is:

```
workspace.PendEdit(FilePath);
```

That is the only TFS command I need to execute at all. So if there is another way to do that, I'm open to it as well.

Hoping someone has an answer or suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was horrendous, however, the reference to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client by default was set to Copy Local: True, Specific Version: True.

Even though I only have one version of this dll on my system and it's being copied locally, when I set "Specific Version" to False, everything just magically worked.

I'm using VS 2013 and the dll is V12.0.0.0