# How to call GetWorkspace in TFS properly?

Tags: c#, tfs

Currently when I call `GetWorkspace` I get `ItemNotMappedException` exception, but when I iterate over workspaces manually I can get my code working. This is so bizarre that I am wondering if I should call some refresh or something before I call `GetWorkspace`?

Here is my code:

```
Workspace active = null;
using (var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri))
{
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
    VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    // displaying info and manually finding desired workspace
    foreach (var ws in vcs.QueryWorkspaces(null, vcs.AuthorizedUser, Environment.MachineName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ws.Name);
        foreach (var f in ws.Folders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  {f.LocalItem}");
            if (f.LocalItem == map_path)
                active = ws;
        }
    }

    // at this point workspace is found and I can work with it

    // but this will crash
    Workspace workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace(map_path);        
}
```

I use VS2015 and the library for TFS is fetched from NuGet repo. It is "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" version "15.112.1".

Comment: Is this a duplicate of the following? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976960/issue-with-tfs-versioncontrolserver-getworkspace-throwing-itemnotmappedexception

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken, thank you, but no, I will update my question in a second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace` method  searches all known workspaces on the current computer to identify a workspace that has explicitly or implicitly **mapped the provided local path**. If no workspace is found, this method throws an [ItemNotMappedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.itemnotmappedexception(v=vs.120).aspx).

Try to call to [`Workstation.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workstation.ensureupdateworkspaceinfocache(v=vs.120).aspx) in your code to force update the workspace information cache:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("<your-tfs-uri-here>"));
VersionControlServer tfServer = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache(tfServer, tfServer.AuthorizedUser);
```

Have a look at this similar question: [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemNotMappedException even when the workspace exists and has a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902276/microsoft-teamfoundation-versioncontrol-client-itemnotmappedexception-even-when)